# Does Django flush the request.session object on User Login?

Tags: python, django, session, django-socialauth

I am setting a session variable in my Django application, like this:

```
request.session['something'] = True
```

After this, I am redirecting the user to Login (`via facebook - django-social-auth`). After the user is successfully logged in, my session variable is lost. I know this because:-

```
if "something" in request.session -- is returning False
```

Does Django flush the session object on login/logout (using the Django Authentication System) or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `login` [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#67):

```
def login(request, user):
    """
    Persist a user id and a backend in the request. This way a user doesn't
    have to reauthenticate on every request. Note that data set during
    the anonymous session is retained when the user logs in.
    """
```

So, if you set something in the anonymous `request.session` it will be there after logging in.

`login` flushes the session only `if the existing session corresponds to a different authenticated user`.

`logout` always flushes the session ([source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#104)).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Alright, that means Django doesn't flush it. But what about django-social-auth? (https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) Could that be doing it, because it is the one handling my login procedure. I tried going through it's source, but I don't really know where to look. BTW, if not sessions, what else can I use?

Comment: Well, I've not found anything related in `django-social-auth` source. Can you check if `_auth_user_id` key is in `request.session` before logging in?

Comment: Well, nevermind. I am using Cookies instead of sessions, as they seem to be doing the job well. Thank you for your help! :)